# git: does git merge command, internally create a new branch?

Tags: git

This question may sound silly, and I am pretty much an amateur in git, but does the git merge or git pull command, creates a new branch when there are conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. merge creates a new commit. If you have conflicts which you have to resolve, these changes also goes to the same commit.

See the Description section in this page https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html

Answer (score 0):

No new branch. But you will have a new revision in the merged branch with the conflict resolution.